# Why Won't the Print Function and Score Keep Working?

Tags: python

I have been working on a rock, paper, scissors game for a school project and have begun to work on the code for score keeping.
When I test the game everything works fine except for the part where it says who won and it doesn't add a point to the win, lose or draw scores.
My main issue is the fact that it does not print the text saying who won and what beat what.
How can I make this work?

Here is my code so far:

```
import random

win = 0

loss = 0

draw = 0
# first scores

while True:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    # asks user for name
    if name.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter characters A-Z only")
    # makes sure user only enters letters
    # taken from Stack Overflow

games = int(input(name + ', Enter in number of plays between 1 and 7: '))
# asks user how many games they want to play
if games >= 7:
    print('1 to 7 only')
    # makes sure user input doesn't exceed seven plays

while True:
    user_play = input("Select r, p, or s: ")
    # asks user to play rock, paper or scissors
    if user_play.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter characters A-Z only")

com_choice = ['r', 'p', 's']
print(random.choice(com_choice))
# Prints a random item from the list as the computer's choice

if user_play == com_choice:
    print('Draw!')
    draw = draw + 1
    # if the user plays the same move as the computer, one point goes to draw

elif user_play == 'r' and com_choice == 'p':
    print('Paper beats rock.')
    print('AI wins!')
    loss = loss + 1
    # if the user plays rock and computer plays paper, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category

elif user_play == 'r' and com_choice == 's':
    print('Rock beats scissors.')
    print(name + ' wins!')
    win = win + 1
    # if the user plays rock and computer plays scissors, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category

elif user_play == 'p' and com_choice == 'r':
    print('Paper beats rock.')
    print(name + ' wins!')
    win = win + 1
    # if the user plays paper and computer plays rock, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category

elif user_play == 'p' and com_choice == 's':
    print('Scissors beats paper.')
    print('AI wins!')
    loss = loss + 1
    # if the user playspaper and scissors plays paper, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category

elif user_play == 's' and com_choice == 'r':
    print('Rock beats scissors.')
    print('AI wins!')
    loss = loss + 1
    # if the user plays scissors and computer plays rock, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category

elif user_play == 's' and com_choice == 'p':
    print('Scissors beats paper.')
    print(name + ' wins!')
    win = win + 1
    # if the user plays scissors and computer plays paper, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category
```

Comment: It runs it once and never does anything with the score. What is the question

Comment: Your script only plays one round of the game. Every time you run the script it starts at 0 again. You need a loop to run multiple rounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 3 issues with your code, 2 quite serious and 1 pretty small:

- It lacked a loop over the number of games
- It compared a string with a list, i.e.: `if user_play == com_choice:` and all the other comparisons
- It didn't validate the user choice, i.e: `if user_play.isalpha():` doesn't inputs as `'a'`, `'b'`, and so on...

```
import random

win = 0

loss = 0

draw = 0
# first scores

while True:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    # asks user for name
    if name.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter characters A-Z only")
    # makes sure user only enters letters
    # taken from Stack Overflow

games = int(input(name + ', Enter in number of plays between 1 and 7: '))
# asks user how many games they want to play
if games >= 7:
    print('1 to 7 only')
    # makes sure user input doesn't exceed seven plays

choices = ['r', 'p', 's'] # the possible choices

for i in range(games): # the loop is needed to play multiple games
    print(f"Match {i+1}, trust your instinct")
    while True:
        user_play = input("Select r, p, or s: ")
        # asks user to play rock, paper or scissors
        if user_play in choices:              # checks user input
            break                             # if valid breaks the loop
        print("Please enter only r, p, or s") # otherwise asks again

    com_choice = random.choice(choices) # assigns the computer choice
    print(com_choice)
    # Prints a random item from the list as the computer's choice
    
    if user_play == com_choice: # now the comparisons are correct
        print('Draw!')
        draw = draw + 1
        # if the user plays the same move as the computer, one point goes to draw
    
    elif user_play == 'r' and com_choice == 'p':
        print('Paper beats rock.')
        print('AI wins!')
        loss = loss + 1
        # if the user plays rock and computer plays paper, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category
    
    elif user_play == 'r' and com_choice == 's':
        print('Rock beats scissors.')
        print(name + ' wins!')
        win = win + 1
        # if the user plays rock and computer plays scissors, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category
    
    elif user_play == 'p' and com_choice == 'r':
        print('Paper beats rock.')
        print(name + ' wins!')
        win = win + 1
        # if the user plays paper and computer plays rock, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category
    
    elif user_play == 'p' and com_choice == 's':
        print('Scissors beats paper.')
        print('AI wins!')
        loss = loss + 1
        # if the user playspaper and scissors plays paper, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category
    
    elif user_play == 's' and com_choice == 'r':
        print('Rock beats scissors.')
        print('AI wins!')
        loss = loss + 1
        # if the user plays scissors and computer plays rock, says that the computer won and puts a point in the loss category
    
    elif user_play == 's' and com_choice == 'p':
        print('Scissors beats paper.')
        print(name + ' wins!')
        win = win + 1
        # if the user plays scissors and computer plays paper, says that the person won and puts a point in the win category
```

**Now you have to check the scores to know the winner**